# Mysql query for selecting friends

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, foreign-keys

I am trying to solve this "issue", however still without success. What I'd like to achieve is, create a query that will select all friends of specific actor. Let's say I want to get list of First name, Last name and age of Jason Statham's friends.

Below is an image of tables.
PS: Are those tables correctly organized ? (especially those foreign keys)
Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: So lets see your tries.

Comment: This is copy & paste of your homework assignment. The reason it is a homework is to teach you something. Why dont you research, read book on that topic and figure it out? At the end when you are out of school looking for a job, there will not be a `stackoverflow` to help you on interview. Take my advice and do it yourself. You will appreciate programming more.

Comment: Thats not a homework btw, I have already tried something like SELECT Actors.first_name, Actors.last_name from Friends_List NATURAL JOIN Actors WHERE loginA='xstad'; 
However it also returns Jason Statham, and I dont want him there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you're looking for?

```
SELECT  actors.first_name,
        actors.last_name
FROM    actors
WHERE   actors.login IN
(
    SELECT  friendslist.loginf
    FROM    friendslist
    WHERE   friendslist.logina = 'xstad'
)
```

Comment: Thanks, works fine, could you please explain me, why my solution was adding there also an actor, whose friends i was looking for ?
thats, what i had SELECT Actors.first_name, Actors.last_name from Friends_List NATURAL JOIN Actors WHERE loginA='xstad';

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Could you rephrase?

Comment: Ah, sorry :) Your solution works fine, but before I asked for help here, that's what I had: SELECT Actors.first_name, Actors.last_name from Friends_List NATURAL JOIN Actors WHERE loginA='xstad'. However, that query returned also Jason Statam. So, list for Jason Statham's friends looked like: Arnold Schwarzeneger, Bruce Willis, Marlon Brando, Jason Statham

Comment: I like to avoid `NATURAL JOIN` in most situations because the logic is clearer when you specify the join manually.  I suspect what's happening is that the `NATURAL JOIN` algorithm is, behind the scenes, joining both columns in `friendslist` to `actors.login`.  I can't tell for sure without further analysis, though.

Comment: @TrippKinetics See my answer below to understand how and why one uses use natural join.

Comment: @philip Oh, I know how to use `NATURAL JOIN`s.  I just prefer not to.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include the Actors table twice - once for the focus person (Jason Statham) and once for his friends.

```
SELECT CONCAT(A.first_name," ",A.last_name) AS Actor, CONCAT(B.first_name," ",B.last_name) AS Friend
FROM Actors AS A
JOIN [Friends List] AS F on A.login=F.loginA
JOIN Actors AS B on F.loginB=B.login
ORDER BY A.last_name, B.last_name
```

Answer (score 0):

If Friends_List is rows where "[loginA] and [loginF] are friends" then rows should appear in pairs, < a1,a2> and < a2,a1>. I'll assume it means "[loginA] considers [loginF] a friend" and that in your query "all friends of an actor" means "all actors that an actor considers a friend".

You can do this with natural join. It joins on common columns and returns only one column with that name. If you want two differently named columns joined to each other then you have to rename one. Unfortunately in SQL you can't do that by just mentioning the one column, you must mention them all.

```
// first_name, last_name of rows satisfying [login] has name [first_name] [last_name] AND 'xstad' considers [login] a friend
SELECT first_name,last_name
FROM Actors
NATURAL JOIN
    (SELECT loginA, loginF AS login
    FROM
        (SELECT * FROM Friends_List WHERE loginA='xstad')
    )
```

(You could collapse the nested selects but I am illustrating the structure.)

You could also use NATURAL JOIN without renaming but explicity equating columns:

```
// <firstname,last_name> of rows satisfying [login] has name [first_name] [last_name] AND [login] considers [login] a friend AND loginA='xstad' AND login=loginF
SELECT first_name,last_name
FROM Actors
NATURAL JOIN Friends_List
WHERE loginA='xstad' AND login=loginF
```

EDIT

A certain design & programming style not familiar to or understood by most SQL programmers is supported by natural join. This approach lets relational algebra operators parallel logic operators: result rows satisfy the statement that is the AND of the statements that argument rows satisfy; UNION the OR; EXCEPT the AND NOT; PROJECT on all but some columns {C,...} the EXISTS C,..; etc.) This is simpler than having to deal with the dotted duplicate columns from SQL INNER JOIN. Unfortunately SQL does not give all the relevant support (eg rename columns, project out columns, no SQL pseudo-3VL, optimizations).

EDIT corrected 1st query